# Showing continuity of a function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $p: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^n}$ be a differentiable function. Define $h:\mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^n}$ by:

$h(s,t) :=$ $\left\{\begin{matrix}
 \frac{p(s)-p(t)}{s-t}& \textrm{if } s \neq t\\ 
p'(s) & \textrm{if } s=t
\end{matrix}\right.$

Prove that if $p'$ is continuous at $t \in \mathbb{R}$, then $h$ is continuous at $(t,t) \in \mathbb{R^2}$.

Can someone possibly give me some guidance as to how to prove this? (i.e. useful theorems, where to start, etc.)

Comment: Notice lim of h as t->s is the the derivative; p'(s)

Comment: What is the limit of $h$ when $(s,t)\to(a,a)$?

Comment: the limit is $p'$ ? @Jonas

Answer (score 0):

$p'$ is continuos $\implies$ $p$ is differentiable $\implies$$\lim_{s\to t}{h(s,t)}$ exists and is equal to $p'(t) \implies$ h is continuos when $s=t$

Moreover, $p$ is differentiable $\implies$ p is continuos $\implies h(s,t)=\frac{p(s)-p(t)}{s-t}$ is continuuos when $s\ne t$

So, $h(s,t)$ is continuos for all $(s,t) \in \Bbb R^2$